# How to acheive Bottom to Top layout (Btt)?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a floating button which reveal a list of buttons when it is clicked.
The animation should expand vertically from the bottom to top.
This works automatically when i'm using a `Scaffold`, but I also want to embed my list in a `PopUp`,to detect if the floating button should be dismissed.

Unfortunately, when using a PopUp, this animation:

```kotlin
AnimatedVisibility(
    visibleState = expandedState,
    content = content,
    enter = fadeIn() + expandVertically(),
    exit = fadeOut() + shrinkVertically(),
)
```

doesn't works as expected. It expand from Top to Bottom.

Comment: Can you edit your post and also include the code of the Popup? And if you could also add a gif screenrecording of how the animation currently looks, we will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the direction of [`expandVertically`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/package-summary#expandVertically(androidx.compose.animation.core.FiniteAnimationSpec,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Vertical,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)), you can use the `expandFrom` parameter. Try them out as follows:

```
enter = expandVertically(expandFrom = Alignment.Top)
// or
enter = expandVertically(expandFrom = Alignment.Bottom)  // set by default
```

However, by default it should already exand from bottom, so I think in your case there might be an issue coming from using AnimatedVisibility within a Popup.